# Mongo atlas, user with restricted access to a single database doesn't see it when connected

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to create a production user in [Mongo atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) which isn't an admin.

- **Right now I've created a new database `anatoly-dev` with a collection `fingerprints` in my cluster:**

[image]

- **And created a new user which suppose to have access only to the above database:**

[image]

When I connect with this user in Robo3T (Robomongo) I don't see `anatoly-dev`.
I use the same connection properties as I connect with admin user except username/password/default database which I defined as `anatoly-dev`

This is URI which is generated by Atlas and which I use:

`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster****.mongodb.net/anatoly-dev?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was an issue with Robo3T not with Atlas or permissions. For more details please refer to this feature update: [Manually specify visible databases](https://blog.robomongo.org/robo-3t-1-4/#a2)

In general, beginning from Robo 3T 1.4 you can and obviously you must manually specify visible database upon connection if your user hasn't admin privileges.

> The motivation for this feature was this problem when the users without admin role privileges (or have access to a specific database), were unable to get the list of databases and so the connection was successful but there were no visible databases (as result of failed listdatabases command).

[image]